# How to unload a project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In VS2008, I can find this context menu item when right-clicking a project in Solution Explorer.

In VS2012, I cannot find such item. How to archive the same in VS2012?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the option isn't available when you right click the project/solution try selecting the project you want to unload then opening the project menu. The option should be available there.